Spring boot 3 : package javax.jws.soap does not exist
We have been migrating our app to Spring Boot 3. We see an error :
`package javax.jws does not exist
[ERROR]  package javax.jws.soap does not exist
[ERROR]  cannot find symbol  class WebService
[ERROR]  cannot find symbol symbol: class SOAPBinding`
when generating files from wsdl. I tried adding
    <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxws-ri</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>

But the error still persists.Any pointers would be very helpful.Thanks
Sucessful build after resolving errors

Spring Boot 3 uses Jakarta EE 9, and you must migrate the rest of the application completely from javax to jakarta. This is stated in Spring Boot 3 migration guide.
To help you migrate check the Open Rewrite recipe. You can run it from Maven command line.

Thank you Caiovss..We have been working on moving to jakarata. The rest of the projects build fine. This error happens in our producer module in the auto generated file from wsdl. Could it be with some of the jars?

Try to run mvn dependency:tree and check if some javax is being added to the classpath by one of your project dependencies.
